# How to read data from Excel files and insert into a Sqlite Database using PHP

Tags: php, excel, sqlite, phpexcel, phpdesktop

I have a sqlite database named: **db** with table named **student**, columns: **name** and **email**. Similarly I have excel file **studentdb.xlsx** having the similar column name with thousand of rows. I want to read the excel file and import the data into sqlite database through a php script. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use a third party library like `SimpleExcel`.

Parsing an Excel 2003 XML file, simplified:

```
<?php

use SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel;

require_once('../your/project/directory/here/lib/SimpleExcel/SimpleExcel.php'); // load the main class file (if you're not using autoloader)

$excel = new SimpleExcel('xml');                    // instantiate new object (will automatically construct the parser & writer type as XML)

$excel->parser->loadFile('example.xml');            // load an XML file from server to be parsed

$foo = $excel->parser->getField();                  // get complete array of the table
$bar = $excel->parser->getRow(3);                   // get specific array from the specified row (3rd row)
$baz = $excel->parser->getColumn(4);                // get specific array from the specified column (4th row)
$qux = $excel->parser->getCell(2,1);                // get specific data from the specified cell (2nd row in 1st column)

echo '<pre>';
print_r($foo);                                      // echo the array
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

[Reference](http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-php/api/0.3/)

Comment: Can you please elaborate the solution @Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: Hello all Problem is solved! I used the PHPExcel Library to import the rows from **xlsx** file to **sqlite** database.I took help from here: [link](http://www.discussdesk.com/import-excel-file-data-in-mysql-database-using-PHP.htm)